# How to disable first section in tableview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I get rid of the first sectionBar here, right above the 'Home' ?

[image: First section]

Comment: Could you show us your code? Specifically, your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, and perhaps the framework that you're using (is it [`MMDrawerController`](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (section == 0) {
    return nil;
}
}
```

or this :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```